# How is memory allocated when opening a zip archive with Go's archive/zip?

Tags: go, memory

For context, I am trying to parse many text files which are compressed in a single .zip archive using Go. I plan to run the application with a machine that has limited RAM, so I want to know how Go allocates memory for the reader of the archive. For example, if I open an archive which (uncompressed) occupies 1Gb of disk space, does Go need to allocate 1Gb of memory to parse all the files?

Comment: Try it.  Looking at the code I think the memory required is probably based on the size of files opened concurrently, not overall archive size.  But memory profiling is the best way to a good answer.

Comment: No, Go does not extract the whole archive in memory. That's why it returns io.Reader(Closer)s, both in the [original API](https://pkg.go.dev/archive/zip#File.Open) and the [modernized](https://pkg.go.dev/archive/zip#Reader.Open).

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, as suggested by @DanielFarrell, I created a Docker instance with the Go code, reading from the .zip archive, and its memory consumption never surpassed 40MB. Profiling with `pprof`, the `inuse_space` of the `main` func was about 1500 kB